# How can I get session value from local php webform into webservice

Tags: php, web-services, webforms, session-variables

I'm new at php and built webservice in file called `soap.php`.
My webform files are in the same folder with `soap.php`.

How can I get session value from my **webservice** through `soap.php`?

Comment: `Am I in the right direction?` .....

Comment: I was meant to ask if it is right attitude to put soap file in the same folder and to assume it will get the session info

Comment: I recommend to watch a video on the basics like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-07Bj14P2v0

Answer (score 0):

Start a session and set values (example):

```
session_start();
$_SESSION ['name'] = 'Soap';
```

And get them on another page:

```
echo $_SESSION ['name'];
```

Be awere, you need to start the session on each page (on the top) otherwise you'll get a 'headers already sent by' error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my question is if I can get this session value from webservice and not from webform

Comment: @ofirparnass Look the echo part, that's how to get them. But if you want to get session values you've to set them otherwise they will be unset.